# Suppressing the automatic tooltip on a DevExpress WPF GridControl - possible?

Tags: wpf, devexpress, gridcontrol

I'm using the DevExpress WPF grid control.  When you hover the mouse over a grid cell, and that grid cell is too small to display the entire value, a tooltip is automatically generated containing the full value, like this: (sorry, print-screen doesn't capture the mouse pointer)

[image]

Is there any way to suppress this?  Ideally, i'd like to suppress it for only certain grid columns if possible.

The MSDN documentation for the event FrameworkElement.ToolTipOpening (exposed by the grid column) says:

*To prevent a tooltip from appearing in the UI, your handler for ToolTipOpening can mark the ToolTipEventArgs event data handled.*

However, I've tried that, and it doesn't work in this case.  Other posts on the web refer to using a TooltipController, but since I'm using the WPF grid, there's no such class (that I can see).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can forbid toltip by setting the column's Settings.ShowTooltipForTrimmedText to false.

Comment: Hi there.  I see no such property on the GridColumn.  I am using the WPF GridColumn DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.v10.2.GridColumn.  Can you please provide a code sample?  The documentation at http://www.devexpress.com/Support/OnlineHelp.xml shows that property exists on TextEdit, but not on GridColumn.

Comment: Here is the xaml:                    <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Country" >
                        <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                            <dxe:TextEditSettings ShowTooltipForTrimmedText="False" />
                        </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                    </dxg:GridColumn>